# c++ std::map compare function leads to runtime "bad_function_call"

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, types

I'm declaring my std::map and use it below:

```
    map<int, int, function<bool (int, int)>> m;
    m.insert(make_pair(12,3));
    m.insert(make_pair(3,4));
    for(auto & p : m){
        cout << p.first << "," << p.second << endl;
    }
```

g++ compiles, no error.
Template parameter only requires a type, but no function body is required, passes compilation. I was wondering how this empty comparer would behave. On running it:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call'
  what():  bad_function_call
```

I only see this error in calling pure virtual function. But my code is using stl template, no polymorphism is in place.

So is this a c++ design issue, that compilation doesn't check if a function only has declaration but no function body to run? Plus, how would c++ standard deal with this?

Appreciate your explanations.

Comment: It's totally valid, but you didn't construct your map correctly - you must provide the comparison function. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to the template argument, but that you did not provide an actual value for it when constructing the map.

Note that in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) for the map constructor, there is a `const Compare&` parameter. It is via this parameter that you must give a value for your comparator which in this case is a lambda.

```
explicit map( const Compare& comp,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

For example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto comp = [](int a, int b) { return a > b; };
    map<int, int, function<bool (int, int)>> m(comp);
    m.insert(make_pair(12,3));
    m.insert(make_pair(3,4));
    for(auto & p : m){
        cout << p.first << "," << p.second << endl;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
12,3
3,4
```

Answer (score 2):

`map<int, int, function<bool (int, int)>> m;`

You declared `std::map` to use your own comparator whose signature is `bool(int, int)`, but did not supply a callable functor.

You should declare a real callable object and pass it to constructor so that your map can call it when needed.

```
auto order_by_asc = [](int n1, int n2)->bool {return (n1 < n2); };
std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(int, int)>> m(order_by_asc);
```